# Calculadora de triángulos

Tags: java, android, android-studio, validación, programación-móvil

Quiero validar que no guarde los valores hasta que el usuario ingrese o dos ángulos y un lado o dos lados y un ángulo, como pueden ver tengo un método para un botón y dentro de el una clase para guardar los valores ingresados por el usuario

```
B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
//angulo
                                      double valor1 = Integer.parseInt(ET1.getText().toString());
                                      B1.setEnabled(false);
//lado
                                      double valor2 = Integer.parseInt(ET2.getText().toString());
                                      B1.setEnabled(false);
//angulo
                                      double valor3 = Integer.parseInt(ET3.getText().toString());
                                      B1.setEnabled(false);
//lado
                                      double valor4 = Integer.parseInt(ET4.getText().toString());
                                      B1.setEnabled(false);
//angulo
                                      double valor5 = Integer.parseInt(ET5.getText().toString());
                                      B1.setEnabled(false);
//lado
                                      double valor6 = Integer.parseInt(ET6.getText().toString());
                                      B1.setEnabled(false);
                                  }
                              });
```

Answer (score 0):

Por ahora lo estoy haciendo así pero creo que serían muchas validaciones y mientras pienso en algunas se contradicen y me confundo, creo que existe una forma más simple pero no logro pensar en otra forma

```
B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                  public void onClick(View v) {
                                      if(ET1.getText().toString().isEmpty() && ET3.getText().toString().isEmpty() && ET5.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ingresa dos ángulos y un lado o dos lados y un ángulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                      }else {
                                          if(ET2.getText().toString().isEmpty() && ET4.getText().toString().isEmpty() && ET6.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ingresa dos ángulos y un lado o dos lados y un ángulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                          }else{
                                              if(ET6.getText().toString().isEmpty() && ET4.getText().toString().isEmpty()&& ET5.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                                                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ingresa dos ángulos y un lado o dos lados y un ángulo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                              }
                                          }

                                      }
                                  }
                              });
```